# Infragistics XamDatagrid binding issues

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I have an MVVM C#/WPF app. I'd like to bind a XamDataGrid to one of my view models, so that users can define how they want their results structure - what column is mapped to what variable.
My core holds such dictionary - `Dictionary<string, string>`, and I'd like to wrap it in an `ObservableCollection` and bind to this, rather than copy the data to a `DataTable`. Problem is, I can't add rows this way (the view seems locked for additions) and changes are not saved. My code:

```
    <igDP:XamDataGrid
        Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
        Name="resultStructure"
        DataSource="{Binding VariablesDictionary, Mode=TwoWay}"
        GroupByAreaLocation="None">
        <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
            <igDP:FieldLayoutSettings 
                AllowFieldMoving="WithinLogicalRow"
                AllowAddNew="True" 
                AllowDelete="True" 
                AddNewRecordLocation="OnBottomFixed" />
        </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
    </igDP:XamDataGrid>
```

the view model (relevant part):

```
private ObservableCollection<DictionaryEntry> variablesDictionary;
        public ObservableCollection<DictionaryEntry> VariablesDictionary
        {
            get { return variablesDictionary; }
            set
            {
                variablesDictionary = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(()=>VariablesDictionary);
            }
        }
```

...

```
List<DictionaryEntry> vars = resultStructureModel.Variables.Select(x => new DictionaryEntry {Key = x.Key, Value = x.Value}).ToList();
            VariablesDictionary = new ObservableCollection<DictionaryEntry>(vars);
```

Comment: I don't know about `XamDataGrid` but in ordinary `DataGrid` you should bind to `ItemsSource` instead of `DataSource`.

Comment: `XamDataGrid` doesn't have `ItemsSource` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked eventually was using a `BindingList`. `ObservableCollection` won't let you add rows, but `BindingList` really provides everything I need.

Answer (score 1):

For adding rows, the XamDataGrid uses either [IEditableCollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ieditablecollectionview.aspx).CanAddnew or IBindingList.AllowNew.

If you use a [ListCollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.listcollectionview.aspx) for the DataSource of the grid then you can add new rows.

To use the ListCollectionView with an ObservableCollection, pass the ObservableCollection into the ListCollectionView and then use the CollectionView to bind to the grid.